# Error in my Java code, Grade Book?

Tags: java

I am new to coding, and I am taking an online course to learn Java. I had an assignment to assign (String) letter grades based on (int) grades. I would use a tester program, but I'm not to savvy on how to write such programs yet.

Is there any error in my code:

```
    String letterGrade = "F";
    grade = grade;

    while (grade >= 90)
    {
        letterGrade = "A";
    }
    if (grade >79)
    {
        letterGrade = "B";
    }
    else if (grade > 69)
    {
        letterGrade = "C";
    }
    else if (grade >59)
    {
        letterGrade = "D";
    }

            return letterGrade;
```

Comment: `while (grade >= 90)`???

Comment: `grade = grade;` ???

Comment: Please explain what you think your code is doing and why you think so. Line by line, statement by statement.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in the comments, what do you think is the use of while here.
You should try to understand first what each statement means when you code.
Anyway, You should use 'if' instead of 'while' rest of the stuff seems correct. If you use 'while' and that case seems to be true you will be stuck in the loop forever.

And Testing your program is not difficult just use different test cases at the beginning put grade = 55; // any random test case numbers.

I am really tempted to give you the solution but am not gonna because it is simple enough.